# Why does my storyboard keep resizing my views

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a UIStoryBoard with a ViewController that contains a UITableView.  I added Views above and below the UITableView to act as a header/footer that will scroll with the UITableView, that is all working appropriately.  The problem is when I resize the header/footer Views, they show up correctly in the preview, but they are not the correct size in the app.

Here is how it looks in StoryBoard:

[image: Storyboard]

And when I run it on the app the top View takes up the entire screen.  But here is the weird thing, if I close Xcode and reopen it both the header and footer views have a height of 568, which I'm assuming is why they look so huge in the app.  Why is Xcode resizing these views?  I have tried removing all constraints but it doesn't make any difference.

I actually removed the ViewController entirely from the storyboard and remade it and it is still doing this same behavior.

Here is what it looks like after I restart Xcode:

[image: After restarting Xcode]

**EDIT**
Getting this output in the console:

```
2015-05-06 14:16:43.214 FitHub[16063:674572] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe46b2ac6a0 V:[UILabel:0x7fe46b2ac6f0'Settings']-(16)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fe46b13a7a0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe46b2ad6b0 V:[UIImageView:0x7fe46b2ad700]-(13)-[UILabel:0x7fe46b2ac6f0'Settings']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe46b2b2360 V:|-(16)-[UIImageView:0x7fe46b2ad700]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fe46b13a7a0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe46b2b22e0 V:[UIImageView:0x7fe46b2ad700(35)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe46b2b2030 V:[UILabel:0x7fe46b2ac6f0'Settings'(30)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fe46b2c9360 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x7fe46b13a7a0(568)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe46b2b22e0 V:[UIImageView:0x7fe46b2ad700(35)]>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set up your layout constraints? The preview in Xcode is separate from how it will be displayed at runtime.

Comment: Yes, all constraints are set up correctly, if I don't manually resize the view's frame in code, the image gets stretched all the way up and down the screen, I have a similar ViewController set up and it does not do this, it's so strange.

Comment: Definitely sounds like a constraints issue.  Have you thought about adding your header and footer views as actual header and footers to the table?  Checkout the 'accessing header and footer views' section in the UITableView class reference.

Comment: Would those be different than header and footer for section?

Comment: There are two different things, one is header and footer for the tableview, the other is headers and footers for each section.  I wasn't sure if you were using either of these or if you were just using literal 'views' above and below your table.

Comment: Ya, I just placed the view above and below the tableview in the storyboard, I added a picture of what the constraints look like after I restart Xcode, you can see the view changes the height by itself and throws all the constraints out of whack, maybe it will help some.

Comment: I also added some output from the console talking about breaking constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have been working in the size class of wCompact hRegular, because we are only developing for iPhones in portrait mode.  I had to change the size class to wAny hAny and then resize the frame height from 568 to 110.

I am curious though, is there a reason why I had to do it for this specific controller and not for any other ones?